What is this movie? Professor tries to kill student or student's mother in his house
I remember watching a movie a few years back at a friends house and recall mostly the ending
It was a Professor who tries to kill his student or the student's mother, one of them is his girlfriend. One of them who couldn't get a hold of the other one finally gets to the teachers house to figure out whats going on and ask if he has seen her. There was a fight previously between the teacher and his girlfriend which results in the girlfriend bleeding in the kitchen behind some of the cabinets/bar area and he tries to hide it. Eventually the one looking for the other figures out what is going on and they both end up fighting him in which I think they both escaped. 
Color film, made between 1980s - 2012 and is English. Was on the sky channels in the evening, possibly on one of the horror channels.

Could be Beneath the Darkness

After watching their best friend get murdered, a group of teens struggle to expose a local hero as the vicious killer and keep from becoming his next victims. 

-

Vaughn Ely is a beloved native of a small Texas town with a dark secret. Formerly the star quarterback, now he's the local mortician. When Ely discovers that his wife Rosemary is cheating on him with the high school English teacher's husband, David Moore, he makes sure they can't do it again. First, he kills Rosemary, but he does not bury her body. Instead, he hides it in his house and dances with the body each night, as though she's still alive. Second, he chases down her lover while he's out jogging at night and buries him alive in Rosemary's empty grave.
Two years later, four high school kids, Travis, Danny, Brian and his girlfriend Abby think they see a ghost in Ely's window when they see Ely dance with his wife's body. They assume since Ely's van is gone, that he is not home. They sneak inside and see what is going on. Enraged, Ely chases them down the stairs and grabs Danny before he can get away. Travis rushes back inside just in time to see Ely shove Danny down the stairs. Ely taunts Travis as he breaks Danny's neck. Ely declines to press charges against the teens, and the police do not believe Travis' accusations.





@pori suggestion

Is this the movie you are looking for Student Seduction (2003) It sems to match your plot description and time frame.

